# how to keep sharp points using subdivison surface

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have created a beast and I want it to have sharp teeth, but as long as I'm using subdivision surface modifier, the points are smooth. If I try it without the subsurf, they don't look like teeth at all and as long as it is one point, I can't add an aditional edge loop. So how do I get them sharp?

Comment: Select an edge and press `Shift`+`E`, this will "crease" the edge to make it tighter. Move your mouse to change the degree, and click to finish the action. Let me know if that is what you needed.

Comment: Sounds like your model ends in a single point. If that's the case, make the end have a face as well and scale it as small as you can. It won't be noticeable and you can add more detail as needed with edge loops as there won't be any triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your tooth topology should look like:

[image]

You can add more loops to the body of it to shape it differently as you want it.