# Replicating sharp broken glass edges

Tags: modeling

I am inspired by an image from a recent question here. I couldn't figure out how to model (Maybe texture) the look and feel of sharp glass edges around a spherical shape and SubSurf.

[image: Ref image]

Comment: You can set creases on the edges that you need to be sharp. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63770/subsurf-modifier-rounding-sharp-edges and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges/735#735.  Also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23885/how-to-keep-sharp-points-using-subdivison-surface

Answer (score 1):

A quick example

To make glass just model it to how u want it to look, try and keep it as random as u can. 
[image]

Then just add a glass material 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRRN7yzPNQI
btw your glass should look way better if u follow the tutorial i just added the material without doing anything to it in the photo below
[image]

Also if u dont want to use cycles u can just turn down the transparency (alpha) as ive done here https://sketchfab.com/models/177e494fdada4b64b02acf041ae8cfdd
[image]

Edit: Something like this? [image]

Comment: Thank you... but "Spherical" and with a subsurf modifier. And random angled edges so it looks real.

Comment: check edit please

Comment: Ty for your time... but not only no 90' angles but even more random within... like the image

Comment: Needs to be random